# Fastest way to store data from sensors in java

Tags: java, logging, store

I am currently writing a Java application that receives data from various sensors. How often this happens varies, but I believe that my application will receive signals about 100k times per day. I would like to log the data received from a sensor every time the application receives a signal. Because the application does much more than just log sensor data, performance is an issue. I am looking for the best and fastest way to log the data. Thus, I might not use a database, but rather write to a file and keep 1 file per day.

So what is faster? Use a database or log to files? No doubt there is also a lot of options to what logging software to use. Which is the best for my purpose if logging to file is the best option?

The data stored might be used later for analytical purposes, so please keep this in mind as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you first of all to use log4j (or any other logging framework). 
You can use a jdbc appender that writes into the db or any kind of file appender that writes into the file. The point is that your code will be generic enough to be changed later if you like...

In general files are much faster than db access, but there is a place for optimizations here.
If the performance is critical, you can use batching/asynchronous calls to the logging infrastructure.

Comment: to improve perfomance you can use the AsyncAppender which buffers the loglines till a file/db appender can handle them

Answer (score 1):

A free database on a cheap PC should be able to record 10 records per second easily.

A tuned database on a good system or a logger on a cheap PC should be able to write 100 records/lines per second easily.

A tuned logger should be able to write 1000 lines per second easily.

A fast binary logger can perform 1 million records per second easily (depending on the size of the record)

Your requirement is about 1.2 records per second per signal which should be able to achieve any way you like.  I assume you want to be able to query your data so you want it in a database eventually so I would put it there.

Comment: Thank you for those numbers! I would +1 if I could. Anyway, what you don't take into account is that my application does other tasks as well, not just logging the sensor data. I will go for a logger for now and then perhaps change it with a DB later on if performance allows. Thanks again for the number. Will be used for future reference

Comment: I assume when you "receive signals" this results in multiple records. If you are using a database you might want to combine these into a single transaction and this can improve performance significantly.

Comment: 1 received "signal" = 1 stored record in file or db

Comment: In that case the simplest way to speed it up, though I suspect you don't need to, is to pass the database update to an ExecutorService so it becomes a background task.

Answer (score 0):

Ah the world of embedded systems. I had a similar problem when working with a hovercraft. I solved it with a separate computer(you can do this with a separate program) over the local area network that would just SIT and LISTEN as a server for logs I sent to it. The FileWriter program was written in C++. This must solve two problems of yours. First is the obvious performance gain while writing the logs. And secondly the Java program is FREED of writing any logs at all(but will act as a proxy) and can concentrate on performance critical tasks. Using a DB for this is going to be an overkill, except if you're using SQLite.

Good luck!

Comment: So, what you are saying is that I should call a C++ program from my Java application that logs the sensor data?

I am not that familiar with C++ so I am not sure how this works.

Comment: you could write it in any other language. I just mentioned C++ because I engineered a solution in it. But you could write it in Java as well. Its freeing your performance critical Java program from doing the book keeping, its like an assistant program, if you will :-)